# Can I define a simple trigger from a standalone script?

Tags: gsuite-addons

Specifically, I want to use the [`onSelectionChange(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) event to show a sidebar depending on what's in the selected cell. The problem is: the project I am working on is a standalone script. So I want to know if there is a way to use the `onOpen` event (for example) and check if the script is being run from a spreadsheet and somehow 'inject' the trigger.

Comment: Do you want to use one editor in particular? (Spreadsheets, Slides, Forms, etc..)

Comment: Yes, I am using the SpreadsheetApp

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far

Comment: I didn't mess with code that much, because I couldn't get the trigger to fire, I thought the problem had more to do with some configuration. Anyway, I posted it in the answer. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying something pretty much like in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee), but I never got it to fire, I guess because it was a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound).

```js
const onSelectionChange = (e) => {
  Logger.log(`onSelectionChange triggered: ${e.toString()}`);
  const { range } = e;
  if (range.getNumRows() === 1 && range.getNumColumns() === 1) {
    range.setBackground('green');
  }
};
```

So the actual solution for me was to create a new document with [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp). Using the command:

```sh
npx clasp create --type sheets --title "foo" --rootDir ./dist
```

and then uploading the script to this new project.